# Set Ag-Grid License key using REST call

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am evaluating an enterprise license version of Ag-Grid in my Angular application. As per official document, it is suggested to use `LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('my key')` inside main.ts file before Angular bootstrap. I follow the procedure and I am able to launch the grid without any error.

Problem starts, when I don't want to commit my key inside the public github repository. Hence, I am getting it from my live server, by putting it manually there in system variable and accessing it by REST call (using crypto-js encryption). Now, if I have to get the key from REST call, I need to make a XMLHttpRequest before Angular bootstrap and I have to make sure angular bootstrap logic goes inside the success and failure of that REST call.

Now, these looks not good for me at all as:

- There will be an extra network latency for my application to start
- Bootstrap dependency on REST call.
- Using XMLHttpRequest instead of Angular's HttpClient.

Is there any good way to setup this license key ? Can I set it during `ng build --myCustomConfiguration_LicenseKey='XYZ'`, which I can pass it from build tool (Teamcity) ?

Note:

- I tried making a REST call inside AppComponent or XMLHttpRequest call
  in bootstrap success method but still I am getting error in console
  that I am not using license version of the app. If I hard-code it ,
  it works fine.
- I am forced not to use git-secret or any other library.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good way to setup this license key ? Can I set it during ng build --myCustomConfiguration_LicenseKey='XYZ', which I can pass it from build tool (Teamcity) ?

Yes - without using REST call.

Once you do `ng build --prod`, the `LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('#my_key#')` part of your code goes into `main.<randomString>.js` file of the generated output.

You can have one powershell script (or shell script) which replaces `#my_key#` with your actual license key.

OR

1. In your CI, once you get the latest code, replace `#my_key#` with your actual license key in `main.ts` file with powershell (or shell) script. Add this step to your CI.
2. Trigger `ng build --prod`

Comment: Thanks Paritosh for your response , but in this case my key will be visible to my browser source code clearly, even though I do a production minified build.

Comment: That's right if you don't want that. Anyways, will keep the answer - perhaps it'll be helpful to someone else.